# ASP.NET VNEXT Reference 4.5.1 Project "Could not be resolved"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

So, I have spent the past two days trying to fix this problem with ASP.NET VNEXT. I have a VNEXT Web application in which I have included a project class library as follows:

[image]

After adding the reference to my class library project, I get the infamous *Could not be resolved*.  The `wrap` folder seems to be created successfully, but it still cannot resolve it in the VNEXT app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Dependencies are resolved through NuGet packages. Is your other library available in one of your NuGet sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this working, I had to create a new ASP.NET 5 web project from scratch and add all of my code to it.  Once I did this, everything began working fine.